# Why gradle task runs in wrong order?

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, adb

I want to run task for copy screenshots from android devices after UI test.
I added to build.gradle in module:

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == 'connectedMyAppDebugSources') {
        task.finalizedBy {
            // here is my task
        }
    }
}
```

when I use this task:

```
def fetchScreenshotsTask = task('fetchScreenshots', type: Exec, group: 'reporting') {
    executable "${android.getAdbExe().toString()}"
    args 'pull', '/sdcard/Pictures/screenshots/.', reportDirectory
}
```

task runs at the end, but this task not work if tests run on several devices.
Then I created task that get id for all running devices and run another copy task for each devices:

```
task fetchScreenshotsForAllDeviceTask(group: 'reporting') {

String result = ""
new ByteArrayOutputStream().withStream { os ->
    def output = exec {
        executable "${android.getAdbExe().toString()}"
        args 'devices'
        standardOutput = os
    }
    result = os.toString()

}

List list = result.split('\n')
            .collect {it.split('\t').head()}
            .drop(1)

for(String item: list) {
    createDir(item)
    copy(item)
    clear(item)
    }
}
```

and this is "copy" task for each devices:

```
def copy(String device) {
    def copyTask = exec {
        executable "${android.getAdbExe().toString()}"
        args '-s', item, 'pull', '/sdcard/Pictures/screenshots/.', reportDirectory
    }
}
```

Problem is:
Task fetchScreenshotsForAllDeviceTask runs at the beginning of the tests, when I insert it in block:

```
 task.finalizedBy {
            // here is my task
        }
```

Whereas "fetchScreenshotsTask" runs at the end if I put it in this same block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Task fetchScreenshotsForAllDeviceTask(group: 'reporting') runs in counfiguration phase gradle lifecycle.
To run this task in execution phase need run this task in doLast block, or add "<<" to task:

```
task fetchScreenshotsForAllDeviceTask(group: 'reporting') << {
//here is task code
}
```